# Creation of Database to replace multiple excel entry forms

Tags: database, excel

I have been given a project from work and although I have built multiple databases before, for some reason this one is stumping me. I need to create a database to capture data which was previously being captured on multiple spreadsheets to simplify the statistics program at my company. Each spreadsheet captured key pieces of information, I've attached an example of each. Each sheet needs to be set up so that an individual can enter their information for their location and that one person (me) can enter the full company information. For example the hours form, from this form I need to capture the employee count and manhours, whereas from the district sheet I need to capture contractor hours, vehicle data (second tab), and performance data on a monthly basis. The final entry needs to be able to enter all of the counts on the counts link form in order to create a table similar to the link form. Can anyone help me figure out where to start, I have been feeling like hitting my head against the wall for about an hour now and cannot figure out where to begin.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nnjh0x14k5jei7w/Database%20Files.zip

Comment: Try including what you've tried so far, and if there are specifics of what you're getting stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

I'll help get you started on the hours form. Create a table as follows:

```
DIVISION (northeast, Rocky Mountain, etc)
REGION (Southern Appalachia, none, etc)
OFFICE (Houston Office, SASG Shop, etc)
RIG
EMPLOYEE_COUNT
MAN_HOURS
```

The first three items will help you sum up the totals. Later on, you can normalize the division, region, office values to create dropdowns and share across multiple forms.

For the other forms, you'll follow a similar process. Start with the columns you need to track and add in columns to help you group things. Don't worry about who's entering what for now.